# How to find count of digits in string variable using scala?

Tags: scala

I have a string variable like below

```
val str="raid11112233rdfg"
```

If i wanted to find the count of digits in string variable using scala how to solve this.Ideally it should give output as count of 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

such as

```
str.count(_.isDigit)
```

might just work.